# Using Amazon EC2 Ipaddress access application outside network

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, cloud

I configured the security group for my ec2 instance as shown below. I deployed my application in tomcat on port 8085:

```
SECURITY GROUP
-----------------
custome tcp   8085  0.0.0.0/0
```

Using my ec2 ip  I am not able to access my application
http://58.62.30.195:8085/HealthProd

I am able to access my app using localhost like

http://localhost:8085/HealthProd

Comment: Is this an inbound or outbound rule? It needs to be an inbound rule for this to work. Also make sure that the security group is assigned to your instance.

Comment: yes this is inbound rule. and also assigned to my instance. already I did this.

Comment: Is your instance inside VPC? If yes, in public subnet? Assigning a public IP to a private subnet instance does not mean it can be accessed from the internet.

Comment: So, we need  to configure our application in particular domain or what are you are trying to say. Rakesh please explain little more details.

Comment: Private IP 172.67.55.345
Public IP  58.62.30.195
Elastic IP 58.62.30.195 These are my ip . .please read my question I want like http://58.62.30.195:8085/HealthProd . waht is the solution

Comment: @muledevlepoer24 - Did you create your instance inside a VPC?

Comment: Yes . instance inside vpc. how to access my elastic ip  in public network

Comment: You will either have to put the instance in public subnet of your VPC or create a load balance in public subnet and give ELB access to instances. FYI, If you decide to go ELB way, you cannot assign elastic IP to it.